# What is the difference between s.length and sizeof(a)?

Tags: c++, string

```
string s;
cin>>s;
int a[s.length()];
for(int i=0,j=0;i<s.length();i=i+2,j++)
{
    a[j] = s[i]-48;
}

int Asize1 = s.length()/2+1; //3
int Asize = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); //5
```

Why these two statements  give different results(3 & 5)?
I thought they should've been same.

Comment: This is not valid C++ code - C++ does not support VLA

Comment: Can you share why you expect the statements to be equivalent? Then we might be able to figure out where your confusion lies.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux For an example ,if i input 3+2+1 ,this loop will remove those plus signs making it an integer array of [3,2,1]. thats why i am expecting it to be of size 3 not 5.

Comment: @ShayerMahmud that loop does not remove anything from the string.

Comment: OK i understood.I didnt know about VLA. Thanks to all :)

Comment: @Slava `i` is incremented by 2, skipping every other `char`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ?

Comment: @Slava Because `i=i+2` and the copy is done by reading `s[i]` it copies about half the characters from the original string.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ok my confusion I thought OP expects size of `s` change.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with your array `a` is invalid in C++ since C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Some compilers add it as an extension though, so lets continue with that assumption.

The variable `ASize1` is initialized to the length of the string *divided by `2` and then added `1`*. So you're not really checking the same thing.

If the length of the string is `5`, then `s.length() / 2 + 1` will be `5 / 2 + 1` which is `2 + 1` which is indeed `3`.

Assuming that the compiler implements VLA's "correctly", then the expression `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])` will be equal to `(5 * sizeof(int)) / sizeof(int)` which will be `5` as expected.

---

For completeness, lets do it with a `std::vector<int>` instead, with the equivalence of the code shown in the question:

```
string s;
cin>>s;
std::vector<int> a(s.length());
for(int i=0,j=0;i<s.length();i=i+2,j++)
{
    a[j] = s[i]-48;
}

int Asize1 = s.length()/2+1; //3
int Asize = a.size(); //5
```

If the input string is five characters, then my explanation still holds (except that it's `a.size()` that returns `5`). The difference between the number is because you divide the length of the string by `2` and add `1`, which is not done for the vector length.

To get the proper length of the vector, you either need to create it with the correct size to begin with, or by starting with an empty vector and then adding the values.

Comment: Who said that `sizeof(a) == 5 * sizeof(int)` ?

Comment: @Slava it's assumed by the answer that the length of the string is 5 by *"If the length of the string is `5`"*.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux even so who said what `sizeof()` would return in this case?  C++ standard quote maybe?

Comment: @Slava You know that it's impossible since VLA's are not in the standard. This whole answer assumes that the compiler allows it (as stated in my answer) and that e.g. `sizeof` would do the correct thing.

Comment: @Slava You know as well as I do that there is no such quote, since this question uses non-standard extensions.

Comment: Then there is no point of explanation what to expect from ill-formed program. If I start to explain how rvalue to non const-lvalue reference would work in C++ and side effects how many downvotes I would get?

Answer (score 0):

You use C functionality that is not valid in C++ - Variable Length Array. Anyway using it or not operations on array do not change it's size (which is returned by `sizeof()`) and it does not matter how many assignments you did in that loop. For proper logic use `std::vector` which maintains size:

```
string s = "3+2+1";
std::vector<int> v;
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i+=2)
{
    v.push_back( s[i]-48 );
}
```

[live code](https://ideone.com/tqCq8h)